# Troubleshoot asp.net core restarts in azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I've got an asp.net core web app that runs, quite hapily (most of the time), in Azure as an windows app service.

However, we sometimes see the web app restarts occaisionly - sometimes in bursts, say 10 in a minute, and we're not sure why this is happening. We know it's probably not something on Azure's side, becuase  our web jobs continue to run and don't restart.

My theory is that something pretty bad happens in the web app, and crashes the dotnet process, so it restarts. However I can't see any evidence of this happening - no event logs, or anything that I can analyse. Is it possible to add logging in azure, so that if something does take down dotnet and cause it to restart, we can find out more?

Comment: Check out this answer(the update part), it should help you to troubleshoot the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021644/is-there-way-to-determine-why-azure-app-service-restarted

Comment: Thanks - I should add that I've checked Azure's diagnostics, and it doesn't report any restart events, even though my own logs show this is happening.

Comment: Maybe it just about `The default configuration for windows azure websites and cloud services is to unload your application if it have not been access for a certain amount of time. It makes a lot of sense for
Microsoft to do this, as they save resources on by stopping infrequently accessed sites.`

Comment: You can also enable `Always On`..form the docs `Always On. By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time. If your app runs continuous WebJobs or runs WebJobs triggered using a CRON expression, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably.`. Source:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure

Comment: Yup, `AlwaysOn` is on, and this is a very traffic-heavy site (again, I should have added that in the description)

Comment: have you tried to turn on the tracing for core web app? https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Troubleshooting-.NET-Core-errors