# Azure App service needs restart after a period of inactivity

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a .net core app running on Azure App Service. I have "always on" enabled in configurations settings and the apps runs well but after a period of inactivity, I need to restart the service to  be able to hit its endpoints. Wondering anyone has dealt with this before and know how to solve this and basically have my service run all the times

Comment: If you need periodic tasks I would look into Azure Function TimerTrigger

Comment: What is the app service plan you are using? Consumption, Standard or Premium? If you don't restart the service, what is the error you are getting when hitting the end points?

Comment: @AnupamChand I am using Standard S1.

Comment: @VovaBilyachat I need it to always be on without having to restart it

Comment: @AnupamChand I get a `could not send request: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myendpoint.com` in postman

Comment: Could You please refer this  similar thread [Why is my webservice restarting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d692c19-4533-4cd9-ae93-9285ee483660/why-is-my-webservice-restarting?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) /  [Azure web apps restart at random .](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b84732d6-f125-4f13-9509-614cee75cc25/azure-web-apps-restart-at-random?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) / and [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021644/is-there-way-to-determine-why-azure-app-service-restarted) .

Answer (score 0):

As you have already enabled **ALWAYS ON**  based on this [discussion|MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d692c19-4533-4cd9-ae93-9285ee483660/why-is-my-webservice-restarting?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) .

Run it directly from Kudu Console outside of the WebJobs framework, Check  [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues)  .

You may also  review the WebJob deployment files and application design logic for any triggers which causes a restart.

Please refer the below links for more information:

. [Azure web apps restart at random | MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b84732d6-f125-4f13-9509-614cee75cc25/azure-web-apps-restart-at-random?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) .

.Similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021644/is-there-way-to-determine-why-azure-app-service-restarted) .